# $(a,b) \mathbin\# (c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b) \mathbin\&(c,d)=(ac-bd(r^2+s^2), ad+bc+2rbd)$. Multiplicative inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, inverse

Let $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $0\neq s \in \mathbb{R}$. Define operations $\#$ and $\&$ on $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ by $(a,b) \mathbin\#(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b) \mathbin\&(c,d)=(ac-bd(r^2+s^2), ad+bc+2rbd)$ as addition and multiplication, respectively. Do these operations form a field?

I have shown that every axiom of the field is satisfied except for the "existence of multiplicative inverses" axiom. This is where I need help. We either need to show that this axiom fails and so we don't have a field or that the axiom $aa^{-1}=1$ is satisfied for every $a\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$

The multiplicative identity in this problem is $(1,0)$.

Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar enough to the pair-based definition of the complex numbers that it looks promising to explore how far that analogy will take us.

First, it is easy to see that multiplying *any* pair by $(a,0)$ simply scales both of its elements by $a$. If we identify $(a,0)$ with the usual real numbers (that is sort of handwavy but bear with me for a moment) and we give $(0,1)$ a name $x$, we can represent the pair $(a,b)$ as $a+bx$, and you already know that the *ring* axioms hold, so we can handle such expressions by the usual rules.

Since you have checked that the distributive law holds, multiplication has to work like
$$ (a+bx)(c+dx) = ac + (ad+bc)x + bdx^2 $$
and by comparison with your multiplication rule we see that
$$ x^2 = -(r^2+s^2) + 2rx $$
This gives us a quadratic equation that $x$ has to satisfy, and if we just pretend the quadratic formula will work in this setting, we can solve to get
$$ x = r \pm |s|\sqrt{-1} $$

Now all of the above is not very rigorous, but it *does* strongly suggest that what you have your hands on are just the complex numbers under a non-standard representation. So what we should do to get back on a rigorous footing is to verify from first principles that
$$ f(a,b) = a + b(r+si) $$
is a **ring isomorphism** $(\mathbb R^2,\#,\&)\to\mathbb C$. It is not difficult to see that it is a ring homomorphism, and proving that it is bijective is a simple matter of linear algebra.

Since $(\mathbb R^2,\#,\&)$ is isomorphic to a ring that we already know is a field, it must itself be a field.

(You don't need to work out the inverse mapping explicitly, but if you want to you now have enough information to do it relatively painlessly).

---

Note that once you know that $f$ is a bijection that preserves addition and multiplication in the sense that $f(p)+f(q)=f(p\#q)$ and $f(p)f(q)=f(p\&q)$, you can get *all* of the field axioms for free by "pulling them backwards" along $f$ -- not only multiplicative inverse. So the explicit verifications of, say, the associative and distributive laws you have already done will not be strictly necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The addition and multiplication formulas somewhat remind of the formulas for complex number. We suspect that a map of the form
$$ \phi\colon (x,y)\mapsto \alpha x+\beta y$$
for suitable $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb C$ turns out to be a field isomorphism. As we want $(1,0)\mapsto 1$, we conclude $\alpha=1$.
Then 
$$ \phi((a,b)\mathop{\&}(c,d))=\phi(a,b)\phi(c,d)=(a+\beta b)(c+\beta d) = ac+\beta(bc+ad)+\beta^2bd$$
and on the other hand
$$\phi(ac-bd(r^2+s^2),ad+bc+2rbd)=ac-bd(r^2+s^2)+\beta(bc+ad+2rbd)$$
so that we obtain an identity by chosing $\beta$ with $\beta^2=2r\beta-(r^2+s^2)$, i.e., one of the roots of the polynommial  $X^2-2rX+r^2+s^2$.
For $s\ne 0$, this garantees $\beta\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$. Therefore the image of $\phi$ in $\mathbb C$ is more than just $\mathbb R$; as $\phi$ is linear $\mathbb C$ and $F$ both have diemnsion $2$, we conclude that $\phi$ is a vector space isomorphism. As the choice of $\beta$ guaranteed compatibility with multiplication, $\phi$ is indeed a ring isomorphism and as $\mathbb C$ is a field, so is $F$.